# Why does my CPU not support 1G-pages although it reports that it does?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, amd-processor, tlb, cpuid

When I check CPUID 0x80000001u:EDX:26, I get 1, i.e. my CPU says that it supports 1G-pages. But when I do CPUID 0x80000019u EAX - EDX are zero, i.e. my CPU says that there aren't any large page TLBs (Ryzen 7 1800X, Ubuntu Linux). Another PC (Phenom X4 945, Debian) reports 1G-pages).

Answer (score 2):

Did you check for errata?  And did you check Wikichip or other CPU architecture details page to see if there are *dedicated* TLB entries for that, or if they're handled by TLB entries that can also handle 2M largepages or something?

https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Zen.html says there are no L2 ITLB entries for 1G pages, but the L0I and L1I TLB entries can hold any page size.

For data TLBs, 1G pages can be handled by the L1dTLB, but not the L2dTLB, again according to 7-cpu testing and decoding of CPUID results and/or other published data.

[Wikichip agrees](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen#Memory_Hierarchy):

> ITLB:
>
> - 8 entry L0 TLB, **all page sizes**
> - 64 entry L1 TLB, **all page sizes**
> - 512 entry L2 TLB, no 1G pages
> - Parity protected
>
> DTLB
>
> - 64 entry L1 TLB, **all page sizes**
> - 1,532-entry L2 TLB, no 1G pages

IDK how this info is supposed to be reflected in CPUID results, but that's what Zen 1 has, and what you should be looking to explain based on CPUID results.  (If there aren't any errata about wrong TLB info.)

Note that there are no TLB entries on Zen 1 that can *only* cache a 1G translation; any entry capable of caching a 1G hugepage entry is capable of holding other sizes.

(Intel does things differently, where there are separate TLBs for separate page sizes.  https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Skylake.html / https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)#Memory_Hierarchy - separate L1i and d TLBs for each different size (except no L1iTLB for 1G pages).  And unified L2TLB aka STLB with lots of combined 4k+2M entries plus 16 entries for 1G pages.)

Comment: An extended discussion was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238433/discussion-between-peter-cordes-and-bonita-montero).